# Post event to Qt GUI thread to simulate key press

Tags: c++, qt, events

I want to simulate key presses in Qt. I have found some examples online, but have not got it working yet. I have this method:

```
void SimKeyEvent::pressTab()
{
    QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Space, Qt::NoModifier);
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(receiver, event);
}
```

I don't know how to properly address the GUI thread which should be the 'receiver' in the code lines above. What I have tried is passing the 'app':

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
```

through the SimKeyEvent class constructer and made a private pointer to it.

In main.cpp:

```
SimKeyEvent *simKeyEvent = new SimKeyEvent(0, &app);
```

SimKeyEvent.h

```
private:
    QGuiApplication *app;
```

SimKeyEvent constructor:

```
SimKeyEvent::SimKeyEvent(QObject *parent, QGuiApplication *app) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    this->app = app;
}
```

Then I change to:

```
QCoreApplication::postEvent(app, event);
```

This did not work and I don't know if there is something wrong with the code or if its supposed to be done a different way.

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/GC/MainMenu.qml"));

    SimKeyEvent *simKeyEvent = new SimKeyEvent(0, &app);

    viewer.showExpanded();
    return app.exec();
}
```

EDIT:
I also tried using 'this':
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, event);

Comment: Why not just send a signal (called, for example, `tabKeyPressed()`) to  the worker the thread is running ?

Comment: @JBL: Using signal and slots instead you mean? How do one press, e.g. the character 'A' without using the event mechanism?

Comment: Well, you can create the event just as you're doing now, and pass it as a parameter to the signal, i.e. `tabKeyPressed(QKeyEvent* evt)` which maps to, let's say, the slot `handleKeyPressedEvent(QKeyEvent* evt)` of your worker. (Note: There's more specific event, such as `QMouseEvent` or `QKeyEvent`).

Comment: @JBL: Events are new to me and also sending signals with arguments, but if I pass the QKeyEvent to app by QObject::connect() will the GUI then register this as a Tab? If i send it to a slot I still have the same problem: How to programmatically do a "Tab"?

Comment: Doing programmatically a Tab isn't the same thing. I suggest you read a bit more about signals and slots (that'll show helpful, as it is a prominent feature of Qt). Also, you should define in your post what you aim to do (Simulate the key as if the user pressed it, fool a Qt object in thinking he received such event, other ?)

Comment: @JBL: I have used a lot of signals and slots in my program, both in QML and C++ and across domains, but not sending any additional information. I want to simulate key strokes as if the user pressed it (so instead of pressing tab myself I want my application to do it). I understand how this might have been unclear as I am myself confused on how to do it, but am hoping to solve this so I have asked for help. Suggested changes to formulation of the question is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080342/programmatically-press-keyboard-buttons-in-qt) post for the answer to this question.

Code snippet:

```
bool MyWidget::event(QEvent *event)
{
     if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
         QKeyEvent *ke = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
         if (ke->key() == Qt::Key_Tab) {
             // special tab handling here
             return true;
         }
     } else if (event->type() == MyCustomEventType) {
         MyCustomEvent *myEvent = static_cast<MyCustomEvent *>(event);
         // custom event handling here
         return true;
     }
     return QWidget::event(event);
}
```