# Programmatically press keyboard buttons in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

My task sounds simple: I want to programmatically press keyboard buttons in Qt/C++. So I want some lines of code that makes the GUI think some keyboard keys was pressed.

I do not want to use windows specific API if possible.

Can this be done? If so how/where should I get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool MyWidget::event(QEvent *event)
{
     if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
         QKeyEvent *ke = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
         if (ke->key() == Qt::Key_Tab) {
             // special tab handling here
             return true;
         }
     } else if (event->type() == MyCustomEventType) {
         MyCustomEvent *myEvent = static_cast<MyCustomEvent *>(event);
         // custom event handling here
         return true;
     }
     return QWidget::event(event);
}
```

This is a simple example from [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html). The main idea is that you have to send KeyPress event to your window object. [Here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/9718) is another good example.

Comment: If I send this KeyPress event to my window object it will interpret it as if I actually pressed the Tab key etc? Do I override the event method of my main window? From what I read it seems like this overriding of the QObject::event() only allows me to do custom stuff for key presses like Tab etc., but not actually generate it? If you could further explain and/or give example that would be great.

Comment: If you want to handle keypress events - yes, you have to override `::event` method and do what you need. But if you only want to simulate keypress - sending KeyPress event is enough, QWidget class in Qt have it's own base implement of events.

Comment: I get error: QCoreApplication::removePostedEvent: Event of type 6 deleted while posted to QtQuick2ApplicationViewer. Any idea why the events are deleted from queue?

Comment: Post all your code, error and all useful information in new question and close this if my answer answers your question here.

Comment: The answer/code you provided shows how to reimplement parts of the event handler and that is fine but I was asking for how to programmatically press key board buttons. You did provide the answer in a comment stating: "if you only want to simulate keypress - sending KeyPress event is enough, QWidget class in Qt have it's own base implement of events". This comment is to clear up for other users that might read this question. I will start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way to simulate/generate a user key event, is to use the QtTest module.

```
#include <QtTest>
#define QT_WIDGETS_LIB
#include <qtestkeyboard.h>

...

// For example:
QTest::keyClick(QApplication::focusWidget(), key, Qt::NoModifier);

// or even more low level:

qt_handleKeyEvent(widget->windowHandle(), QEvent::KeyPress, key, Qt::NoModifier);
qt_handleKeyEvent(widget->windowHandle(), QEvent::KeyRelease, key, Qt::NoModifier);
```